# Firebase Authentication token doesn't include additionalClaims

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up the following Firebase rule.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "notification": {
      "$notif_id": {
        ".write": "auth.token.notif_id == $notif_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where `auth.token.notif_id == $notif_id` gives a permission denied response and I don't understand why. (*Assume that the `$notif_id` branch was defined as `abcd`*)

I define the Firebase token on my Node.js server as follows:

```
var params = {notif_id:'abcd'};
var firebase_token = Fb.auth().createCustomToken("uid", params);
```

Then within my HTML web browser code I have the following:

```
var db = firebase.database();
function initApp() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      //do nothing
    }
  });
}

$('document').ready(function(){
  initApp();
  firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken('<%=firebase_token%>').catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.error('ERROR: '+errorCode);
    console.error(errorMessage);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the access token (you can get it from the `user` in onAuthStateChanged) and decoding it to see your extra claim? And where do you initiate the read operation? That "do nothing" comment would be a nice place to start.

Comment: Hmm, your code looks correct. Follow the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) to get the signed-in user's ID token and then plug that into [https://jwt.io](https://jwt.io). You should see your custom claim in the top-level of the payload. If so, then your security rule is probably just wrong. Maybe you are actually writing to a different node or `$notif_id` just isn't what you think it is.

Comment: did you solved the issue?